# The Application {name} cannot be resolved error in Version Screen , Design Studio Transact T24 ( IRIS )

Tags: temenos-quantum, temenos

I am trying to build my own API in Design Studio IRIS. I have created a Design Studio Sample Project and then imported a Version Screen from TAFJ server. I want to generate code as war file for pushing it to JBOSS server for further API building  process.
The problem is that after importing Version Screen into Design Studio it red-underlined the Screen Name and show an error "The Application {name} cannot be resolved". I have tried some more random screens but they all are causing same problem. Pls help me how to solve this error so after all I can generate code into .war file
Screen Shot Below:-
[Screen Shot Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG6HY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do "Import T24 Applications" in Design Studio under the xxx-models project.